# Onkeyup Events with Tapestry 5.2.6

Tags: tapestry

I am tring to use the mixins zoneUpdater from Tapestry to trigger an event when I write in a textfield. However I keep getting the following error :

```
Failure creating embedded component 'myComponent' of com.mycompany.myapp.web.pages.tapestryTest.testEdit: Unable to resolve 'zoneUpdater' to a mixin class name.
```

Here is the code in the tml page :

```
<div t:type="zone" t:id="myZone" id="myZone" update="show">
<table><tr>
    <td class="td-right-view"><t:label for="myComponent"/></td>
    <td class="td-left-view"><t:textfield t:id="myComponent"
    value="myValue" t:validate="maxlength=8" maxlength="8"
    style="width:70px;" t:mixins="zoneUpdater" t:clientEvent="keyup" 
    t:event="updateMyValue"  t:zone="myZone"/></td></tr>
</table
</div>
```

In the controller I defined the following method :

```
@OnEvent(component = "updateMyValue")
Object onupdateMyValue()
{
    if (this.value.length()==8){
        //does something
    }

    return myZone.getBody();
}
```

Any idea why I keep getting this problem? I am doing the same thing as on jumpstart but for some reason it doesn't recognise zoneUpdater. I am using Tapestry 5.2.3 so it should work without creating the classes from Jumpstart.

Thanks in advance,
Remi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapestry itself does not have a mixin called ZoneUpdater. The one described on Jumpstart pages (e.g., http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/ajax/onevent) is a custom one. See that link for the source code. Just paste that code into your project.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked, thank you !   I found out another way of doing it, I will post it here asap.